# Flowers "are" or "were" commonly used to design clothing worn in the 1960s?

Tags: tense

May I know which sentence is correct?

1) Flowers ***were*** commonly used to design clothing worn in the 1960s.

2) Flowers ***are*** commonly used to design clothing worn in the 1960s.

Comment: As Andrew's answer, and the comments show, we need more context. What are you intending to say?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to say.  The first sentence is fine, and can be used to talk about clothing designed and worn by people in the 1960s.

> Flowers **were** a common design element of clothing worn in the 1960s.

The second sentence is almost correct, if you are talking about clothing designed *today*, that *looks like* the clothing people used to wear in the 1960s.

> Flowers **are** a common design element of clothing **like that** worn in the 1960s.

Note I changed "commonly used to design" to "a common design element of".  *Flowers* aren't doing the designing, after all.  Another way to phrase this would be:

> Flowers were commonly used **in** designs of clothing worn in the 1960s.

or

> Flowers are commonly used **in** designs of clothing like that worn in the 1960s.

[Edit]  As WendyG points out, your second sentence would be understood to mean currently designed clothing to look like past clothing.  In this case we can think of it as an *ellipsis* in which certain words are omitted, when the intended meaning is obvious from context:

> Flowers are commonly used to design **(the kind of)** clothing **(that was)** worn in the 1960s

In context (using J.R.'s example):

> Clothing designers often use accoutrements and accessories to invoke the styles of a certain era. Fedora hats are commonly used when creating costumes from the 1920s. **Flowers are commonly used to design clothing worn in the 1960s**.

Comment: I read "Flowers are commonly used to design clothing worn in the 1960s." as historical present tense

Comment: @WendyG - Taken by itself, I agree with you. But it’s not hard to imagine a context where Andrew’s interpretation would be the clearly intended one.  For example: _Clothing designers often use accoutrements and accessories to invoke the styles of a certain era. Fedora hats are commonly used when creating costumes from the 1920s. Flowers are commonly used to design clothing worn in the 1960s._

Comment: @WendyG  Sure, but it's an *ellipsis* -- **Flowers are commonly used to design (the kind of) clothing (that was) worn in the 1960s**.  The intended meaning would be apparent from context.  I'll edit to include this interpretation..